# Explain order of constructor/destructor calls in this C++ code

Tags: c++, constructor, order-of-execution

I have this C++ code:

```
class BaseClass {
    int id;
public:
    BaseClass() { printf("BaseClass()\n"); }
    virtual ~BaseClass() { printf("~BaseClass()\n"); }
};

class Class1 : public BaseClass
{
    int id;
public:
    Class1() { printf("Class1()\n"); }
    ~Class1() { printf("~Class1()\n"); }
};

class Class2 : public Class1
{
    BaseClass id;
public:
    Class2() { printf("Class2()\n"); }
    ~Class2() { printf("~Class2()\n"); }
};

class Class3 : virtual public BaseClass
{
    int id;
public:
    Class3() { printf("Class3()\n"); }
    ~Class3() { printf("~Class3()\n"); }
};

class Class4 : public Class3, virtual public Class1
{
    Class3 id;
public:
    Class4() { printf("Class4()\n"); }
    ~Class4() { printf("~Class4()\n"); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    BaseClass *p = new Class2;
    Class2 *p1 = new Class2;
    Class3 *p2 = new Class3;
    delete p;
    delete p1;
    delete p2;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
BaseClass()
Class1()
BaseClass()
Class2()
BaseClass()
Class1()
BaseClass()
Class2()
BaseClass()
Class3()
~Class2()
~BaseClass()
~Class1()
~BaseClass()
~Class2()
~BaseClass()
~Class1()
~BaseClass()
~Class3()
~BaseClass()
```

and I don't understand why. I would expect that the output is the following:

```
BaseClass()
Class1()
Class2()
BaseClass()
Class1()
Class2()
...
```

etc.

Why isn't `Class2()` printed after `Class1()` when creating, for example, `p1`?
Does this have something to do with virtual inheritance?

Comment: When a class A inherits class B, the construction of class B requires class A to be constructed first - as the construction of B may require the use of A

Comment: @songyuanyao I accidentally left out the first line when copying the output, sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go step by step with the first object being constructed:

```
new Class2;
```

This is the first object you're contructing, let's called it `p`.

```
BaseClass()
```

`p`'s `BaseClass`.

```
Class1()
```

`p`'s `Class1`, the subclass of `BaseClass` gets constructed.

```
BaseClass()
```

This is the `id` member of `Class2` being constructed.

```
Class2()
```

And now, finally, `Class2`, `p` itself.

So, despite your belief otherwise, `Class2()` is printed after `Class1()`. Except that you forgot that `Class2` also has an `id` member, that's a `BaseClass`, and which must also be constructed before the `Class2::Class2()` constructor gets invoked. You believed that you were seeing the second `new`ed object's `BaseClass` being constructed, but what was really getting constructed was the `BaseClass` member object.

P.S. This is `C++`. In `C++` we use `std::cout` instead of `printf`(). `printf()` is so ...last century.

Comment: Of course... I completely ignored this, didn't even notice that `id` wasn't an integer like in `BaseClass` and `Class1`. Such a lame mistake :) By the way, it's not my code. :)

Answer (score 3):

> Why isn't Class2() printed after Class1() when creating, for example, p1?

Because `Class2` has a non-static member object with type `BaseClass`, its ctor will be called before the ctor of `Class2`.

According to the [initialization order](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list#Initialization_order):

> Initialization order
>
> 1) If the constructor is for the most-derived class, virtual base
>   classes are initialized in the order in which they appear in
>   depth-first left-to-right traversal of the base class declarations
>   (left-to-right refers to the appearance in base-specifier lists)
>
> 2) Then, direct base classes are initialized in left-to-right order as
>   they appear in this class's base-specifier list
>
> 3) Then, non-static data members are initialized in order of
>   declaration in the class definition.
>
> 4) Finally, the body of the constructor is executed

For `new Class2;`, the direct base class `Class1` and its base class `BaseClass` will be invoked firstly. And then the non-static data member `id` with type `BaseClass` will be invoked. And the body of ctor of `Class2` will be invoked at last. So you'll get

```
BaseClass()
Class1()
BaseClass()
Class2()
```